# Truncating time part in ObjectQuery

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm creating an object query, and have a groupBy clause in query, which looks like this:

```
group by cast(T.Updated as date)
```

but I'm getting an exception:

An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntitySqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Type 'date' could not be found. Make sure that the required schemas are loaded and that the namespaces are imported correctly. Near type name, line 7, column 73.

How can I truncate time part in ObjectQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that maybe you're on SQL Server 2005?  The Date data type was not introduced until version 2008.  You could try:

```
group by dateadd(day,datediff(day, 0, T.Updated), 0)
```

Comment: No, I'm on sql server 2014. The thing is that I'm using ObjectQuery